# Parametric equation - domain question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the curve with parametric equations $$x = \ln(2t), y = t^2, t > 0$$ When I plot the graph on Desmos, the graph looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iojry6dgod).

For some reason, the graph starts at about $x=-10.2...$. However, I don't understand why this is the smallest $x$ value in the domain of the graph.

The lower limit for $t$ is $0$, but $\ln(2*0)$ is not defined and $\ln(2*x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$. Moreover, if I allow $t$ to be negative in Desmos, then the graph seems to extend, but I don't think these equations can accept negative $t$ in the $x$ equation?

Comment: ln$(2t)$ is defined when $t>0$ and it tends to $-\infty$ as $t$ approaches to $0$

Comment: $ln(0.00005)$ is approximately $-10$ I suspect Demos doesn't bother plotting the $y$ values as for t less than this as they are too small, so that's why it appears to start at around $-10$.